# Place transect through two subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a plot that contains two plots within the same axis similar to this:
https://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/pylab_examples/ganged_plots.html

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4],
                xticklabels=[], ylim=(-1.2, 1.2))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4],
                  ylim=(-1.2, 1.2))

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
ax1.plot(np.sin(x))
ax2.plot(np.cos(x));
```

Is there a way I can place transect lines that pass through both plots if I have the specific x coordinate for each line?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do something like this using list comprehension on a list of your axes:

```
[i.axvline(20, color='r') for i in [ax1,ax2]]
```

Output:

[image]